# Why can I create a property with [1] and not with [one]?

Tags: javascript

Why is it that I can create a property with this: `o[4]`

But not with this: `o[five]`

```js
var o = {one: "one", true: "two", three: "three"};

o[4] = "four";

console.log(o);

o[five] = "five";

console.log(o);
```

Comment: `o["five"] = "five";` or `o.five = "five";` but never `o[five] = "five";`, only if five is a variable and stores the property name

Comment: `[five]` involves a reference to a variable called "five", which you have not defined.

Comment: there is no variable called `five`, maybe try it with `"five"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1` is a literal value. `five` (the way you've used it) is an identifier.

You can do `o[five]` to create a property **if** `five` is a declared and initialized identifier; its value will be looked up and used as the property name (possibly being converted to string first).

You can't use `o[five]` to create a property if `five` isn't declared and initialized, because when you try to read the value of an undeclared/uninitialized identifier, it's an error.

In contrast, since `1` is a literal value, you can always use it that way.

You could use `o["five"]` if your intention was to create a property with the name `five`, although `o.five` is the usual way you'd do it if the name you want to use is a valid identifier name. But for instance, `+` is a valid property name but not a valid identifier name, so you'd use `o["+"]` if you needed to create a property with the name `+`.

Some examples:

`five` is undeclared and uninitialized:

```js
const o = {};
o[five] = "five"; // ReferenceError
```

`five` is declared but uninitialized: ¹

```js
const o = {};
o[five] = "five"; // ReferenceError
let five;
```

`five` is declared and initialized:

```js
const o = {};
let five = "something";
o[five] = "five"; // Works
console.log(o);   // {something: "five"}
```

`five` is declared and initialized with the default value `undefined` (bit of an edge case):

```js
const o = {};
let five;
o[five] = "five"; // Works
console.log(o);   // {undefined: "five"}
```

---

¹ Yes, `five` is declared but uninitialized there. `let`, `const`, and the declaration version of `class` declare their identifiers at the top of the containing scope, but don't *initialize* them until the `let`/`const`/`class` is encountered in the step-by-step execution of the code. You can see that at work here:

```js
let a = 1;
{                   // The inner `a` is in scope from here
    console.log(a); // ReferenceError
    let a;          // Declares the inner `a` (and initializes it with
                    // `undefined` when reached in the step-by-step code
                    // execution
}
```

Comment: 1. Does initialise mean successfully assign an identifier|variable a value?
2. Am I right in thinking that: the dot way of making properties only works if the key is a valid identifier; this isn’t the case with brackets.

Comment: @tonitone110 - 1. Yes, although "successfully" doesn't really come into it. :-) 2. Right. Dot notation only allows you to use property names that are valid according to the "identifier name" syntax in the spec ([here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-names-and-keywords)). For instance, to be a valid identifier name, it has to start with a letter or other non-digit identifier character. So `test1` is a valid identifier name, but `1test` is not (because it starts with a digit). But with brackets notation using a string, you can create a property with basically any name.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better if you play it around php tester and not in here.

but you can do this instead.

```
o.five = "five";
```

Instead of

```
o[five] = "five";
```

```js
var o = {one: "one", true: "two", three: "three"};

o[4] = "four";

console.log(o);

//o[five] = "five";
o.five = "five";
o['six'] = "six";

console.log(o);
```